# Receiving a Nintex workflow error in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Please help with the error:

Failed to invoke web service. Error returned from server: <soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Association with name 'ROI_HRTraining

I Have checked the workflow and I'm not sure what could be the problem

Comment: Based on the error message provided, it seems that there is an issue with invoking a web service in the Nintex workflow in SharePoint 2019. The error message indicates that there is an association with the name 'ROI_HRTraining' that is causing the issue. It is possible that there is an issue with the configuration of the web service or the association in the workflow. I would recommend reviewing the configuration of the web service and the association in the workflow to ensure that they are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To identify issue, you have to perform below action:

- Before proceed make sure you have a backup of your workflow.
- Make sure there is no any warning with yellow exclamation mark.
- Create a new Workflow with any action (Email or Log History) and check its publish or not?
- Try to disable / delete actions one by one and publish workflow.
- Create a new workflow and Import existing workflow and try to publish it.

In most of the cases, Nintex does not provide exact error message.